# GXT-Valueprovider as Tooltip

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I am struggling with a gwt/gxt problem. I've been using Sencha ValueProvider for grids and similar for quite some time without any trouble. Now I want to create a Cell wich gets an additional ValueProvider to display the Tooltip. For example I have a column with CustomerNames and the Tooltip is supposed to display the customerNumber. 
Unfortunately I can't figure out how the ValueProvider works internally. I know, that I somehow have to use the Path-Attribute but I still can't get the correct value to be displayed.

I would be very thankful for suggestions!

Comment: ValueProviders use getters mentioned in your POJO, to get the values. If yoy are providing the literal @Path("name"),for the method fullName() in ValueProvider interface, it will search for getName() in the POJO, else it will search for getFullName() in POJO. (getter of the method). 

Path provides something like id. It is generally the method name i.e fullName, will be returned as Path. It can be used as unique id for column.